# Symfony 6 and PhpStorm, methods in the extended class are not recognized

Tags: phpstorm, symfony6

I use PhpStorm 2019.2 , it works good with Symfony 4 but with Symfony 6 and PHP 8.12 I get some errors like this:

[image]

and also the methods in the extended class are not recognized, such as `render()`, `createForm()` etc.

[image]

[image]

I've tried Invalidate Caches and restart IDE but no changes.

Comment: *"I use PhpStorm 2019.2"* PhpStorm 2019.x does not support PHP 8. It supports max PHP 7.4 (not even in full; you need 2019.3 for that). I suggest you download latest 2021.3 (or even try 2022.1 EAP build) and check there. You can run them in parallel (each major IDE version stores IDE-wide config in a separate folder). https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/nextversion/

Comment: But speaking in general: normally such an issue would be resolved with Invalidate Caches... But you have tried that already and that did not helped. Therefore I think it's something specific to PHP 8 support... which your version does not support.

Comment: yes, I have updated phpStorm to 2021.3.1 and it's ok now. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally such kind of issues ("Method 'xxx' not found in XXX" and alike) would be resolved with Invalidate Caches... But you have tried that already and that did not helped. Therefore I think that it's something specific to PHP 8... which your IDE version does not support.

> I use PhpStorm 2019.2 , it works good with Symfony 4 but with Symfony 6 and php 8.12 I get some errors like this:

**PhpStorm 2019.x does not support PHP 8.** It supports max PHP 7.4 (not even in full in your 2019.2; you need 2019.3 for that).

I suggest you download latest 2021.3 (or even try 2022.1 EAP build) and check there. I'm sure it will behave much better there. You can run them in parallel with your current version (each major IDE version stores IDE-wide config in a separate folder). Just do not open the same project in multiple versions at the same time.

You can download PhpStorm from these links:

- Latest stable (2021.3.2): https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/download/
- EAP builds (next major 2022.1): https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/nextversion/ (major EAP builds are free to use; they come with own 30-days license so anyone can use it).